# Android Video chat and server

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Я хочу написать что-то типо видеочата между несколькими Android телефонами.При этом чтобы видеопоток шел напрямую между телефонами(Клиентами), а сервер (PC) лишь связывал их между собой. Нужно это чтобы не создавать нагрузку на сервер. Возможна ли такая схема вообще? Я честно сильно плаваю в этой теме и не знаю точно как работает передача данных. При этом все API что я нагуглил предлагают писать подобное на их платформах без участия сервера.Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать и какими API можно было бы воспользоваться для этого.

Comment: Покопайте протоколы rtsp/rtmp.медиа сервер ред 5.а так только с телефонами , это не реально

Comment: Ещё ngnix +rtmp  модуль.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен точно, но я бы посмотрел в сторону сокетов.

Возможно по уроку ниже можно будет приспособить сокеты для видеопотока.

[Передача данных по сети при помощи socket при разработке android приложения](https://sidstudio.com.ua/sidstudio-blog/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-socket-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)